# Nginx only replace root domain (keep subdomain)

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, url-rewriting

I've got currently this domain:

https://api.app.com/content.

Now I want to redirect all incoming urls to:

https://api.app-2.com/content.

So I only want to replace the root domain (subdomain and directory must be inherited). Is that even possible with an nginx rewrite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered a simple redirect from the old domain to the new one?

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name foo.old-domain.com;

  # Redirect everything to the new domain
  return 301 http://foo.new-domain.com$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name foo.new-domain.com;

  location / {
    # Print the URL you're visiting
    add_header Content-Type text/plain;
    return 200 "URL: $uri";
  }
}
```

Comment: What if I removed reidrect and only use the new domain in the `sever_name`?

Comment: @Nithur the short answer is "it depends". The requests to the unconfigured host may appear on a default server, or on the one that NGINX read first. You'd better ask this on ServerFault for a detailed answer (if nobody haven't done this yet).